# ¿Como rellenar un formulario reactivo en angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, formularios, angular7

Necesito rellenar el formulario con los datos del usuario para poder editarlos, pero no se como hacerlo.

Este es el formulario.

```
 this.formEditarUser = this._builder.group({
  name: ['', Validators.required],
  cpostal: ['', Validators.required],
  provincia: ['', Validators.required],
  localidad: ['', Validators.required],
  pais: ['', Validators.required],
  surname: ['', Validators.required],
  imagen: [''],
});
```

Intente meterlo en la funcion que me trae los datos del usuario, pero da error, e intento rellenarlo con una funcion a parte pero tampoco se rellena.

```
rellenarFormuluario() {

this.formEditarUser.value.name.setValue(this.nombre);
```

}

Solo se visualiza en el formulario si lo hago directamente en el constructor.

Aquí le asigno el nombre a la variable

```
getUserEditar() {
this._serviceUser.edit(this.idUserConectado).subscribe(
  response => {
    this.user = response;
    this.nombre = response.name;
    this.rellenarFormuluario();
    console.log(this.formEditarUser.value.name);
  }
);
```

}

Comment: puedes poner lo que tiene la variable `this.nombre`?

Comment: ya lo modifique le asigno el nombre que me trae el response, aunque se lo ponga manualmente tampoco funciona.

Comment: quieres rellenar todos los campos del formulario o solo el `name`? Es que no queda claro

Comment: Todos los campos, pero antes quería conseguirlo con uno, antes de hacer los demas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para rellenar los campos de un formulario reactivo angular te provee dos métodos `patchValue` y `setValue`. [Aquí](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#updating-parts-of-the-data-model) la documentación.

*patchValue* actualiza todos los campos que encuentre en el modelo que le pases como parámetro. Sino encuentra un campo no tira ningún error.

*setValue* es más estricto a la hora de actualizar los valores, es decir, valida que el modelo tenga la misma estructura y propiedades que los campos del formulario. Si falta alguno tira error.

Imagina que en tu caso quieres actualizar solo los campos `name` y `cpostal`.

Si usas **patchValue** la actualización no te dará error.

```
this.formEditarUser.patchValue({ name: 'mi nombre', cpostal: 'abcd12'});
```

Pero con **setValue** te dará error porque te faltan pasar los campos que no se actualizan.

```
this.formEditarUser.setValue({ name: 'mi nombre', cpostal: 'abcd12'}); // dará error
```

Para actualizar todos los campos del formulario

```
rellenarFormuluario() {
   this.formEditarUser.patchValue(this.user);
   // this.formEditarUser.setValue(this.user); esto depende de ti si quieres que tenga una validación estricta o no. 
}
```

Actualiar campo individual

```
// haces el get del campo que quieres actualizar y haces el update del valor con patchValue o setValue. 
this.formEditarUser.get('name').patchValue(this.nombre);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!